# Compare empty ASCII char in PHP

Tags: php

I have a very simple question. When I do the following in PHP:

```
 echo (rawurldecode('%20') =='');
```

I always get `false`, but my expected behaviour is that is should be `true`. In other words, I would like to check whether a variable is empty, because the variable can have some parameters passed from a URL.

Comment: `'%20'` is not empty, it's a space...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you consider space as "empty" then do a trim on the rawurldecode output.

```
echo (trim(rawurldecode('%20')) =='');
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to check if a variable is empty, than you can easily use the [`empty()`](http://php.net/empty) function, built in PHP.